# Dynamic background in Android fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to change the background of a fragment based on the time of the day (light for day, dark for night). Right now, I hard coded the background image in the fragment's layout:

`android:background="@drawable/weatherbg"`

But to have a dynamic background, I assume that I have to do that in the fragment activity class, inside the onCreate method?
I'm not sure how though, since you cannot use setContentView in fragments.
I know I have to write some conditional code, but not sure what's the method to set the background image inside a fragment.

This is my first experience with Android, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you want to implement dark mode?

Comment: @JimaleAbdi Hi, no I do not want to implement dark mode, I'm just trying to have a day/night background because the page displays the weather forecast.

Comment: OK I think you have one drawable for day and one for night if that's yes it's easy to implement but detecting whether is day or night it needs some attention

Comment: @JimaleAbdi yes, but how do I call the drawable/set the background in my activity? Right now I set it in the layout xml but I don't think you can have a conditional statement there (?) (like ```if day: background="@drawable/day"``` )

Answer (score 0):

you can change background by using `setBackgroundResource()`, but you must give id for your `View`

```
RelativeLayout rl;    

 rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1); // the id of the view


 rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day_image); // change the background
```

fro detect whether is day or night you can use [this](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api) free API also look [this](https://darksky.net/dev/docs)

Comment: Thanks! However I did the following in my weather fragment and it did not work:                                  
             ```public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weather, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.weatherbg);``` Might it be that in my styles.xml, I set a theme for the whole app? Do I need smt extra to override that? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: if you are using fragment refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692162/android-change-background-color-of-fragment)